# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException on Toggle Buttons to assign double value

Tags: java, android, exception, togglebutton, numberformatexception

I am getting this exception in certain devices mostly API29. So am assigning double rounded values to Toggle buttons. When the user clicks on them it adds that value to the current total, then convert that total into a String in order to be displayed in a TextView.

I have tried adding the exception but it fails to display the double price assigned to the toggle button.

Also, I viewed some other threades in here which wehere not helpful.

The code is below; Any guidance on this?

```
private void setListeners() {


        //boolean chemoIsChecked = false;

        chemoBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

                    if (isChecked) {
                        try{

                            Double chemoPrice = Double.valueOf(chemoButtonPrice);
                            d = chemoPrice + d;
                            String totalPrice = String.valueOf(String.format(Locale.GERMAN, "%.2f", d));
                            premiumTitle.setText("Premie per maand incl. BTW: € " + totalPrice);

                        }catch (NumberFormatException e){

                        }

                    } else {
                        try{

                        }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                            Double chemoPrice = Double.valueOf(chemoButtonPrice);
                            d = d - chemoPrice;
                            String totalPrice = String.valueOf(String.format(Locale.GERMAN,"%.2f", d));
                            premiumTitle.setText("Premie per maand incl. BTW: € " + totalPrice);
                        }

                    }

            }
        });

        cremBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Double cremPrice = Double.valueOf(cremationButtonPrice);
                    d = cremPrice + d;
                    String totalPrice = String.valueOf(String.format(Locale.GERMAN,"%.2f", d));
                    premiumTitle.setText("Premie per maand incl. BTW: € " + totalPrice);
                } else {
                    Double cremPrice = Double.valueOf(cremationButtonPrice);
                    d = d - cremPrice;
                    String totalPrice = String.valueOf(String.format(Locale.GERMAN,"%.2f", d));
                    premiumTitle.setText("Premie per maand incl. BTW: € " + totalPrice);
                }
            }

        });

        travenBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Double travelPrice = Double.valueOf(travelButtonPrice);
                    d = travelPrice + d;
                    String totalPrice = String.valueOf(String.format(Locale.GERMAN,"%.2f", d));
                    premiumTitle.setText("Premie per maand incl. BTW: € " + totalPrice);
                } else {
                    Double travelPrice = Double.valueOf(travelButtonPrice);
                    d = d - travelPrice;
                    String totalPrice = String.valueOf(String.format(Locale.GERMAN,"%.2f", d));
                    premiumTitle.setText("Premie per maand incl. BTW: € " + totalPrice);
                }
            }

        });

        btnContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                createAdditionalPackages();


}
```

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3,78"
       at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString + 2043(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
       at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble + 110(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
       at java.lang.Double.parseDouble + 538(Double.java:538)
       at java.lang.Double.valueOf + 502(Double.java:502)
       at nl.risk.www.smart2coverapp.activity.PetplanAdditionalPlansActivity$2.onCheckedChanged + 165(PetplanAdditionalPlansActivity.java:165)
       at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked + 182(CompoundButton.java:182)
       at android.widget.ToggleButton.setChecked + 71(ToggleButton.java:71)
       at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle + 136(CompoundButton.java:136)
       at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick + 141(CompoundButton.java:141)
       at android.view.View.performClickInternal + 7312(View.java:7312)
       at android.view.View.access$3200 + 846(View.java:846)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run + 27794(View.java:27794)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 873(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 99(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 214(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 7099(ActivityThread.java:7099)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 494(RuntimeInit.java:494)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 965(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Comment: "3,78" try with 3.78 its's point instead of comma

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing:

```
Double travelPrice = Double.valueOf(travelButtonPrice);
```

convert first the commas to dots with [replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)):

```
Double travelPrice = Double.valueOf(travelButtonPrice.replace(",", "."));
```

Comment: This app runs in Netherland and I just realized I have added Germany as Locale. IN Netherlands they use a comma instead of a dot. How do you fix this?

Comment: The comma is to print the value. But to store a value as a double it doesn't matter the locale you have, you always need to save doubles with a point as a separator

Comment: yes but is still crashing...

Answer (score 0):

Please remove that comma(,) using replace method of String class like below

```
String totalPrice = String.valueOf(String.format(Locale.GERMAN,"%.2f", d)).replace(',', '').trim()
```